# ¿Cómo hacer array_diff trayendo los elementos de los dos array?

Tags: php

Tengo dos *json* que comparo de la siguiente manera:

```
$it_1 = json_decode($value['dato_anterior'], TRUE);
$it_2 = json_decode($value['dato_nuevo'], TRUE);
$result_array = array_diff_ukey($it_1,$it_2);
```

Lo hago para obtener un log de cambios en `$result_array` obtengo la diferencia pero lo que necesito es obtener los elementos de los dos array's para mostrar el dato anterior y el dato nuevo.

Comment: No entiendo, si tienes el dato anterior `$value['dato_anterior']` y el dato nuevo `array_diff_ukey($it_1,$it_2`, entonces que necesitas?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de array de entrada y la o las salidas que necesitas.